# how can one combine multiple swagger documents?

Tags: swagger, openapi

how does one combine multiple swagger documents? The documents generated from multiple endpoints need to be made available in a HTML UI.

Comment: Do you mean [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45161533/113116)?

Comment: yes, but want to present it in a different way. will check this out. Thank you

Comment: Do you want to merge documents or to render all in one UI?

Comment: Or do you want to reference one OAS file in another?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following tool I wrote: https://www.npmjs.com/package/openapi-merge-cli