# Deploy OpenAPI to localhost

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

My organization has a lot of APIs for different projects. I need an **OpenAPI** implementation that allows me to create a standalone portal that contains all these APIs (more like a repository) for all our products.

*Is there an **OpenAPI** that supports this?*

Another option would be: to be able to merge several instances to a single OpenAPI instance.

Comment: Swagger UI can [display multiple API definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45161533/113116). Is this what you need?

Comment: I think it does. However Swagger UI is too basic.
@Helen does another implementation of OpenAPI (e.g. ReDoc or readme.io), have this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to implement API catalogs.

#### Swagger UI (open-source)

Swagger UI 3.0.19+ can [display multiple API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45161533/113116) definitions using the `url` parameter.

```js
// index.html

const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
  dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
  urls: [
   {name: "petstore",  url: "http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json"},
   {name: "instagram", url: "https://api.apis.guru/v2/specs/instagram.com/1.0.0/swagger.yaml"}
  ],
  "urls.primaryName": "petstore",  // default spec
  ...
```

Result:

[image: Swagger UI top bar with spec selector]

Since Swagger UI is open source, you can customize its layout and look&feel as your needs dictate.

#### SwaggerHub (commercial)

[**SwaggerHub**](https://swagger.io/tools/swaggerhub/) provides API catalog hosting for teams & organizations, either in the cloud or on premises. SwaggerHub also supports API design, collaboration, code generation and workflow integrations among other things.

*Disclosure: I work for the company that makes SwaggerHub.*

[image: SwaggerHub: API catalog]

Answer (score -1):

To do that, a great solution is to use SwaggerHub as indicated. However, this tool is not free for private API.
I had the same need, so, to help community in OpenAPI design, I wrote a new tool named "OpenAPI Dev Tool" (in github).

With OpenAPI Dev Tool, we can deploy several documentations (for several use contexts) for Swagger UI / Redoc with hot reload feature, like an SwaggerHub.

It is really easy to use.

Each API is indicated in a configuration file :

```
{
    "folder": "./specs",  // Root folder where the specifications are stored
    "specs": [            // Array of specifications (several specifications can be exposed)
        { // First specification file
            "file": "/petstore.yaml", // Relative path of the specification main file (from "folder" parameter). It has to be an OpenAPI file in YAML or JSON.
            "context": {    // Object used for template generation (see Template usage chapter below)
              ...
            }
        },
        { // Second specification file
        "file": "/petstore2.yaml"
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

Then, you can serve the whole API just by hitting `npx openapi-dev-tool serve`
Open your browser with `http://localhost:3000` et voilà :)